# kafka.com:9092/0: Connect to ipv4# failed: Connection refused

Tags: apache-kafka

I use Kafka with one node (version 1.0.0).

why when I set `listeners=PLAINTEXT://138.201.YYYY.YYY:9092`, everything is **OK** and I can produce and consume well in local and client enviroment , but when I set `listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafka1.dev:9092`, in the client side, I cannot produce and consume any message and this error will appear‍‍ :

```
%3|1531686738.672|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka1.dev:9092/0]: kafka1.dev:9092/0: Failed to resolve 'kafka1.dev:9092': Name or service not known
%3|1531686738.672|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka1.dev:9092/0]: kafka1.dev:9092/0: Failed to resolve 'kafka1.dev:9092': Name or service not known
```

and I have to add `138.201.YYY.YYY kafka1.dev` in the `etc/hosts` file (in local) to fix the problem and produce fine.

Comment: Sounds like your DNS or other networking properties are misconfigured... Where does `64.90.XX.XX` come from? Why is it not `138.201.YYYY.YYY`?

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks. Yes, I was having trouble with the network, and now I'm updating the question.

Comment: Again, I don't think this is a Kafka problem. Your DNS cannot resolve `kafka.dev` for whatever reason. For example, `nslookup` or `dig` should be commands for checking that FQDN is resolvable